# Hello World .ane and test in adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe

Today I want to make an import of a .ane, but I need a very simple to so that you can use it. I would like to do a test where I can import a .ane.

Sb know a helloWorld .ane for Androdi ???

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a very simple project - [getting device id from Android/iOS](https://github.com/ktimothy/DeviceToolsANE).